# UITableViewCell Height doesn't change when it load additional data

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UITableView` that loads data from X url then inside each `UITableViewCell` config method, I load more data from Y url.

**The Problem:** I set `UITableViewCell` height to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, and it appears that UITableViewCell doesn't update the height when cells load additional data.

**My Question:** What's the efficient way to load additional data for each cells and update height according to the received content considering I have around 8 components inside each cell so I don't think reloading all cells would be good choice!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you properly setup your constraints in the cells?

Comment: @SanderSaelmans yes I am pretty sure

Comment: Please set UITableViewAutomaticDimension in delegate method ### func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat ### if not already.

Comment: After loading additional data you need to reload that cell

Comment: @Rizwan I already do that

Comment: @dotfreelancer - I hope you have also called tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], animation: .none) when data was loaded ?

Comment: How are you updating the cells?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you need to reload the cell when the data is finally loaded, because tableView needs to recalculate cell height (and the whole contentHeight) when new data arrives

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], animation: .none)
```

Where "indexPath" is indexPath of updated cell

You can call this method for every updated cell when it needed. So you don't need to reload whole table view.

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure to update constraints of updated view inside your customTableViewCell

```
someView.updateConstraints()
```

Comment: You don’t call updateConstraints directly. You call setNeedsUpdateConstraints instead